# Send variable from one page to another in wordpress page (page not found or error)

Tags: php, wordpress

I Have a php form on my index page and once i try to type  and submit it the wordpress is telling me page not found but that page is a existing page.

index page code

```
<form method="post" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/main/">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Main page

```
 Hello <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

just change the variable name "name" to a different variable and it will work

Answer (score 0):

Just change name to uName:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/main/">
    Name: <input type="text" name="uName">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```